# How can I cache a web application locally

Tags: caching, web-applications, web, memcached

In my company, we have a report generation team which maintains a local web application which is horribly slow. These reports get generated weekly. The data for these reports reside inside a database which gets queried through this report portal. I cannot suggest them to change the application in anyway (like memcache etc.) the only option I have is to somehow save these pages locally and relay.

As these are not static pages(they use database to fetch the data), I want to know is there anyway I can store these pages locally by running a cronjob and then have the super fast access for me and my team.

PS:This application doesn't have any authentication these are plain diffs of two files stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of options, but the following one may be easy

Generate HTML page regularly and update the cache (cache entire generated html page with key obtained from the dynamic content uniqueness), with some kind of cronjob as you have mentioned. This job populates all the modified dynamic content @ regular intervals.

Have a wrapper for every dynamic page content to lookup cache. If hit then simply return the already generated HTML page. Else, go through regular flow. 
You can also choose to cache this newly generated page also.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I understand what to do but I want to know how to do?  Specifically this part - "Generate HTML page regularly and update the cache "

Comment: What is the technology of web application? Php or Java based or .net based?

Comment: Every simple web application will generate response html and send back. You can intercept it and cache it. It varies from technology to technology. If it is php we simply do a echo of all response in the php file. You can use a variable to capture all generated html by appending. It is equivalent to the html you receive@ browser. You cache this variable and return when needed without the all processing.